# Convert audio to 8-bit signed PCM

Tags: audio, wav, signed, pcm, 8-bit

I have a .mp4 audio file that I want to convert to a `8-bit unsigned PCM` format for an Arduino Uno using the `TMRpcm` library.

It also could be a `.wav` file. Anyways, I have tried many things to no avail. The closest I got was with Audacity using the `NIST Sphere` codec. I tried to do this with `FFmpeg`, but it only supports *de*muxing `NIST Sphere` files. How do I convert audio to this format on Mac OS X (10.10.2)?

Comment: what is your desired sampling rate ?  bit depth and sampling rate are the two primary factors determining informational density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was trying to convert a corrupt audio file. `Audacity` converted a valid file correctly.

Answer (score 4):

avconv is a fork from ffmpeg ... so use ffmpeg if you wish

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -ar 8000 -acodec pcm_u8 -ac 1 output.wav
```

WAV is the container format for the PCM codec so if you **MUST** have PCM then get into a binary file editor (wxHexEditor is a nice one) and delete the first 44 bytes (its header) of that WAV file

So above gives you 8000 samples per second and a bit depth of 8 bits, and mono.

verify this using

```
avprobe some_video_audio_file.wav
```

[see bit depth listing available using avconv here](https://gist.github.com/scottstensland/087e77a62fd0dc8c9164)